# IE и Microsoft Edge не читают скрипты

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Добрый день! Есть следующий скрипт:

```
        var elseCheckbox = document.getElementById('else-checkbox');
        var burgerCheckbox = document.getElementById('burger');
        var uhChbox = document.getElementById('uh-burger');
        var accountChbox = document.getElementById('account-list__checkbox');
        var varChbox = document.getElementById('bt1-checkbox');
        var cogChbox1 = document.getElementById('cog-ChBox-1');
        var zapChbox = document.getElementById('zapisey');
        var tbEnd = $('.table-end');

        function elseFun() {
            if (elseCheckbox.checked) {
                $('.else').css('display', 'block');
                $('.else-li').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }

        function zapFun() {
            if (zapCheckbox.checked) {
                $('.dataTables_length').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('.dataTables_length').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }

        function mainFun() {
            if (burgerCheckbox.checked) {
                $('.mob-nav').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('.mob-nav').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }

        function btnsFun() {
            if (uhChbox.checked) {
                $('.btns-mob').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('.btns-mob').css('display', 'none');
            }

            if (uhChbox.checked) {
                $('.dataTables_length').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('.dataTables_length').css('display', 'none');
            }

            if (uhChbox.checked) {
                $('.dt-buttons').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('.dt-buttons').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }

        function accFun() {
            if (accountChbox.checked) {
                $('.icon-down').css('transform', 'transform: rotate(180deg)');
                $('.account-list').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('label i.icon-down').css('transform', 'transform: rotate(180deg)');
                $('.account-list').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }


        function lengthFun() {

        }

        function varFun() {
            if (varChbox.checked) {
                $('.btns-list').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('.btns-list').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }

        $("#main-chb").on("change", function() {
          $(".oth-check").prop("checked", this.checked);
        });
        function zapFun() {
            if (zapChbox.checked) {
                $('.dataTables_length').css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $('.dataTables_length').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }

        // function chbFun() {
        //  if (cogChbox1.checked) {
        //      $('.table-end').addClass('checked-cog');
        //  }
        //  else {
        //      $('.table-end').removeClass('class name');
        //  }
        // }
        $("#table").dataTable({
                "paging":   true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info":     true,
        responsive: true,
                responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: 1
        }
            },
            columnDefs: [ {
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false,
                targets:   1
            },
            [
                        { name: 'desktop',  width: Infinity },
                        { name: 'tablet-l', width: 1024 },
                        { name: 'tablet-p', width: 767 },
                        { name: 'mobile-l', width: 480 },
                        { name: 'mobile-p', width: 320 }
                    ]
                 ],
            "columns": [
                    { "width": "50px" },
                    { "width": "50px" },
                    null,
                    null,
                    { "width": "50px" },
                    { "width": "50px" },
                    null,
                    null
                  ], 
            order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
        colReorder: true,
                language: {
                    "processing": "Подождите...",
                    "search": "Поиск:",
                    "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                    "info": "Показано с _START_ до _END_ записей из _TOTAL_",
                    "infoEmpty": "Записи с 0 до 0 из 0 записей",
                    "infoFiltered": "(отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
                    "infoPostFix": "",
                    "loadingRecords": "Загрузка записей...",
                    "zeroRecords": "Записи отсутствуют.",
                    "emptyTable": "В таблице отсутствуют данные",
                    "paginate": {
                    "first": "Первая",
                    "previous": "<",
                    "next": ">",
                    "last": "Последняя"
                    },
                    "aria": {
                    "sortAscending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по возрастанию",
                    "sortDescending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по убыванию"
                    }
                },
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aLengthMenu": [[ 3, 10, 20, 50, 100 ,-1],[ 3, 10,20,50,100,"все"]],
                stateSave: true,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'colvis'
        ],

        });
```

Да, может быть скрипт не самый лучший, но тем не менее во всех браузерах кроме IE и Microsoft Edge он работает нормально. В чём проблема?
Здесь скрипты подключены:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.4.1/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: что конкретно не работает в edge и  ie?

Comment: всё. то есть вообще ничего не работает. ни одного скрипта, хотя js в ie включен

Comment: И что, при этом совсем ничего не пишется в консоли?

Comment: Если это на что-то влияет, то вот: "Код на этой странице запрещает кэширование вперед и назад. Дополнительные сведения см. по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337". Ошибок не выдаёт

Comment: [mcve] сделай..

Comment: Конкурс без воспроизводимого примера вряд ли поможет. От простого куска скрипта без контекста вроде связанного с ним HTML-кода толку мало, нужен нормальный пример